# Did Bruce's mother end up as the Joker?

Tags: character, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-flashpoint-paradox

In *Justice League: the Flashpoint Paradox*, as Barry's memories are being replaced we see that night where Bruce's parents would have been murdered, but thanks to the ripples of the altered timeline, it was Bruce who was killed.

As Bruce's mother is holding him, covering her mouth with her bloodied hands, she takes it away and starts laughing hysterically and the blood on her face looks like a smile similar to that of the Joker's while Bruce's Father who's become Batman seems more obsessed in taking down the Joker.

So in the altered timeline did Bruce's mother end up becoming the Joker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might sound too plain but the answer is yes. The Film didn't explore it more but in comics ( which this film was based on), Martha as the joker was explored in much more details:

> The alternate universe Flashpoint version of Martha Wayne is the Joker (and even resembles Heath Ledger's portrayal as seen in The Dark Knight). After Bruce Wayne is shot and killed by Joe Chill, Martha is unable to cope with her loss so she cuts open her cheeks to create a faux smile. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha_Wayne#Flashpoint)
>
> [image]

And if nothing else then her cameo scene with the crazy laugh is enough proof that she was indeed joker:

[image]

And even in film Batman (Thoman) did interrogate Yo-Yo ( Harley of that alternate timeline) about whereabouts of Joker.